# Nessus report shows iSCSI vulnerability

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, nessus

The IT Manager (my boss) has been running a vulnerabilities scan on a network of servers we have. The report has come back with some interesting vulnerabilities. The one I can't seem to find a lot on is "iSCSI Unauthenticated Target Detection".

What is this vulnerability? How can I fix it?

Comment: http://www.securiteam.com/windowsntfocus/6P01200EAK.html

Comment: Hi, May I know how you solve "iSCSI Unauthenticated Target Detection" ? I got it too.

Comment: Sorry @Sake we have yet to fix this. We are going down the list and just haven't made it to this one yet. When we do I will make sure to post here.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having this problem withn Netezza server (Redhat based)
IBM consultants are taking a look at this also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without sounding pretentious or even giving you a dummy answer that sounds too simple, what you need to do to really see the "meat" of the vulnerability, as well as mitigation solutions and other details, is to drill down into the hosts that contain the vulnerability.  Click on the vulnerability itself and then on the plugin ID#; this will give you a generalized idea of the vuln.  Next, click on an IP address of one of the hosts that is affected and it should tell you last time this vuln was observed, as well as how to mitigate it based on Tenable's recommended actions.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know, until now, you could even click on those numbers in the report. We weren't given much info other than the report in the email from above I will check that out

Comment: Within the Nessus console is where you'll want to click on the numbers and hostnames.  I don't know that they make an exportable report that has actionable items in it.  I should have mentioned that as I assumed you had access to the Nessus console.  If you don't, you can still have someone who does have access get the information I mentioned and export that to you as well.  Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I don't have access at this time but other than the IT Manager I am the most knowledgeable when it come to IT Security in our unit. Its only a matter of time before I do get access. The report seems to have hyperlinks associated to all the ID Numbers.

Comment: Ah, very good, someone included the links then.  That should get you what you need, and at worst you could look over your manager's shoulder to see the info.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine this vulnerability from both "definition" and "impact" sides.

***Definition***
[iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) is a protocol (i.e., a way to interface / talk with) associated with SAN disks that are part of a [Storage Area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network). What it means is, you can interact with the SAN disks using tools that implement this protocol (e.g., [iscsiadm](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/iscsi-initiator.html) can be used to talk to a SAN disk).

***Impact***
What this vulnerability says is this - SAN disks in this network are accessible and they won't even ask you the password! Feel free to browse through what we have kept in our huge storage network (for which we paid, and are continuing to pay, a big sum because the data is important to us)!

[This article](https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/an-interesting-route-to-domain-admin-iscsi/) demonstrates how penetrations testers became domain admin through this vulnerability.

[This paper](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-05/bh-us-05-Dwivedi-update.pdf), presented in BlackHat, provides further information about various weaknesses in iSCSI.

Hope it helps.